# Bert NER model start and end position None after fine-tuning

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition

I have fine-tuned a BERT NER model to my dataset. The base model that I am fine-tuning is “dslim/bert-base-NER”. I have been successfully able to train the model using the following script as refrence:
https://colab.research.google.com/github/NielsRogge/Transformers-Tutorials/blob/master/BERT/Custom_Named_Entity_Recognition_with_BERT_only_first_wordpiece.ipynb#scrollTo=zPDla1mmZiax

The code which does the prediction:

```
from transformers import pipeline, BertTokenizer

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('dslim/bert-base-NER', return_offsets_mapping=True, is_split_into_words=True)
model = BertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained('dslim/bert-base-NER')

pipe = pipeline(task="ner", model=model.to("cpu"), tokenizer=tokenizer, grouped_entities=True)
pipe("this is a Abc Corp. Ltd")
```

The prediction form the base model contained the start and end position of the word in the original text like:

```
{‘entity_group’: ‘ORG’, ‘score’: 0.9992545247077942, ‘word’: ‘A’, ‘start’: 10, ‘end’: 11}
{‘entity_group’: ‘ORG’, ‘score’: 0.998507097363472, ‘word’: ‘##bc Corp Ltd’, ‘start’: 11, ‘end’: 22}
```

While the prediction from the re-trained model is:

```
{‘entity_group’: ‘ORG’, ‘score’: 0.747031033039093, ‘word’: ‘##7’, ‘start’: None, ‘end’: None},
{‘entity_group’: ‘ORG’, ‘score’: 0.9055356582005819, ‘word’: ‘Games , Inc’, ‘start’: None, ‘end’: None}
```

I am passing the ***position ids*** to the model during the training process. I looked at the model training parameters but, could not find a way to pass ***start and end position*** of the words to model training process. I have the start and end position of the tokenized words.

Comment: @cronoik I have updated the question to include the prediction part of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipeline can not return positions when you pass a "slow"-tokenizer. Use a "fast"-tokenizer to get the positions as well:

```py
from transformers import pipeline, BertTokenizer, BertTokenizerFast, BertForTokenClassification

fast_t = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('dslim/bert-base-NER')
slow_t = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('dslim/bert-base-NER')
model = BertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained('dslim/bert-base-NER')


text= "this is a Abc Corp. Ltd"

slow_p = pipeline(task="ner", model=model, tokenizer=slow_t, device="cpu", aggregation_strategy="simple")
print(slow_p(text))
fast_p = pipeline(task="ner", model=model, tokenizer=fast_t, device="cpu", aggregation_strategy="simple")
print(fast_p(text))
```

Output:

```
[{'entity_group': 'ORG', 'score': 0.9992956, 'word': 'A', 'start': None, 'end': None}, {'entity_group': 'ORG', 'score': 0.97245616, 'word': '##bc Corp . Ltd', 'start': None, 'end': None}]
[{'entity_group': 'ORG', 'score': 0.9992956, 'word': 'A', 'start': 10, 'end': 11}, {'entity_group': 'ORG', 'score': 0.97245616, 'word': '##bc Corp. Ltd', 'start': 11, 'end': 23}]
```

Comment: Thank you, After I changed the tokenizer to BertTokenizerFast both for the training and finally using the trained tokenized for inference. I was able to get the start and end position as well.