# Labelling 100k dataset for BERT-NER

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition

How i label dataset untill 100k++ effectively?I will use it for BERT-NER?and if there is method can you give me like code/tutorial/source for implementing?thank you!BTW, dataset i will use for my BERT-NER is N2C2 NLP dataset

Comment: I'm assuming you have an unlabeled dataset without any labels? 
The most straightforward way to label a dataset is to do it manually or by hiring labelers. A more innovative and scalable way is to use programmatic labeling like snorkel AI https://snorkel.ai/programmatic-labeling/.

Comment: N2C2 seems to be a medical dataset so depending on the entities that you would like to extract, you can also start by using an existing AI model like the analytics for health of Azure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/language-service/text-analytics-for-health/quickstart?tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-python

Comment: hey, thanks for gave me advice, but i hear about "active learning", is that appropriate for my condition?

Answer (score 1):

If the main focus is to label many documents (100k+) with named entities, you could run an industry standard NER tool, like spacy: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#named-entities. You can also use the BERT NER model you mention to label all this data, but it might be more challenging, for instance, in terms of the input data format or how long it takes. "Efficient" labeling in terms of time consumption can happen if you run the chosen model in a powerful environment that can support it, e.g., a machine with a GPU. "Efficient" in terms of quality depends highly on the model you choose, e.g., BERT NER on Huggingface reports around 90% accuracy.

Human annotations are of course more reliable, but since you mentioned 100k+ documents, this might not be a viable option because of the high cost. On the other side, if the goal is to finetune the BERT NER model with the n2c2 dataset, then you probably need less data than 100k+ for finetuning. It might make sense to annotate a few data instances manually, check if the performance of the finetuned model is good enough for your application, otherwise try to auto-label more data based on the gold annotations. In this case, some programmatic labeling as mentioned in the comments with Snorkel could help: https://snorkel.ai/named-entity-recognition/.
In general, it is good to know which entities you are interested in and this will also help deciding whether finetuning is necessary, in case a pretrained model does not cover these entities.

In order to finetune an NER model, then the data (n2c2 in your case) needs to be in the appropriate format for the tokenizer and the classification model you will use. For instance, the BERT NER you mention can be found in Huggingface and the data format uses the BIO tags as shown here: https://huggingface.co/dslim/bert-base-NER. More information and code about NER / Token classification in Python with Huggingface/Pytorch can be found here: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/main/examples/legacy/token-classification. Since the post mentions BERT NER, I assume outsourcing the task to avoid coding (with an extra cost) is not an option, e.g., labeling with some OPENAI calls or using an out-of-the-box NER solution of a cloud provider.

If you type "bert ner" on Google there are many step-by-step tutorials about how to do named entity recognition with Huggingface or Pytorch and custom datasets, e.g., how to apply the models, but also how to train/finetune them. Stackoverflow also has code for training/inference with BERT NER: [Bert NER model start and end position None after fine-tuning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76393971/bert-ner-model-start-and-end-position-none-after-fine-tuning).
The n2c2 dataset seems to be medical, so you might benefit from using an NER model trained with data from the medical domain - you can find options in the Huggingface transformers website.

Comment: hey, thanks for gave me advice, but i hear about "active learning", is that appropriate for my condition?

Comment: It is hard to tell, because the post is missing context. If there is budget available and human annotators, you could try to do semi automatic labeling with Prodigy and basically retrain your spacy NER model as you annotate.

Comment: i do this alone, for thesis bachelor

Comment: Do you just need the labels of the dataset for further analysis, or do you have to create a machine learning model for labeling?

Comment: i already have pre train BioBERT, and the provided dataset only for detecting disease only, but i want my model more than just disease, so i have a plan to use N2C2 and manualy labelling at this moment, but i think thats too much manually label for 100k

Comment: Do you mean you used this model https://huggingface.co/drAbreu/bioBERT-NER-BC2GM_corpus ? If you figure out which types of labels you wish to detect, then you can choose from the relevant public pre-trained models and label the large document collection of n2c2 automatically.

Comment: still confuse, because n2c2 is narrative text, and do i need to split word per word and label them manually?or i can involve this pre trained model?still not too understand sorry

Comment: or can you show me overall of process or something like the flow

Comment: I also don't completely understand what your task is. The flow is to first determine which entities you wish to detect, apart from the disease. Then, if a pretrained model is able to find them, you use that, otherwise you'd need a labeled document collection with the desired entities, which can be used for finetuning a pretrained model for the new entities.

Comment: That new finetuned model will then be able to detect the new entities in large collections. I think NER models work on narrative datasets. If you need specific advice about n2c2, please post a new question :)

Comment: because in my mind, that n2c2 narrative medical notes needs to split word by word, convert it to tsv file, and i need to label all of each word, thats the problem i asked in this post, if there is free way without paid apps to do labelling

Comment: Tokenization is one of the first steps for most NLP tasks, including NER. I mentioned already Huggingface has plenty of public models to use for NER labeling for free. For instance, check the link I shared with BERT-NER. There is code and info about the data format there. Please explore some options I shared and then it'd be possible to come back here and post more precise questions. Also please accept my post as the correct answer if you think it answers your question.